# Como mostrar un objeto dentro de un arreglo en angular usando Ngfor?

Tags: angular, aplicación-web, ngfor

Tengo unos datos que tienen la siguiente estructura.

```
(users)
    [
    {
        "id": --,
        "Name": "--",
        "Email": "--",
        "Password": "--",       
        "group": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "--",
        },
        "school": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "--",
        }
      }
    ]
```

Estoy intentando mostrarlos en una tabla usando ngfor

```
                            <tr *ngFor="let users of listUsers">
                            <td><div >{{ users.id}}</div></td>
                            <td><div >{{ users.Name }}</div></td>                 
                            <td><div >{{ users.Email }}</div></td>
                            <td><div >{{ users.Password }}</div></td>
                            <td *ngFor="let group of users.group"><div> 
                            {{group.name}}</div></td>
                            <td><i  class="fas fa-edit text-primary"></i></td>
                          </tr>
```

A pesar de que he visto en otras preguntas que esta es la forma correcta no funciona. He intentado de diferentes soluciones y recibo el error en la consola del navegador:

**ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

Adjunto los archivos ts y el modelo que uso.

```
.ts file:

import { users } from '../../models/users';

listUsers: users[] = [];
ngOnInit(): void { this.getUsers()}

getUsers(){
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.listUsers= data;
    }, error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

models file:

```
export class users{
id: number;
Name: string;
Email: string;
Password: string;
group: any;
school: any;

constructor(Name: string,
    Email: string, Password: string , group: any , school: any){
    this.Name=Name;
    this.Email=Email;
    this.Password=Password;
    this.group= group;
    this.school=school;
}
```

}

Esto es lo que busco mostrar en la tabla y me da error en el group y school.

- id (se muestra correctamente)
- Name (se muestra correctamente)
- Email (se muestra correctamente)
- Password (se muestra correctamente)
- group name error (queda vacio el campo)
- school name error (queda vacio el campo)

En la tabla con la respuesta, me muestra todo el objeto group, es decir:

```
id | Name | Email | Password | group | school
--    --     --      --        id : 1 name: -- createdAt: -- updateAt:--
```

Solo necesito que en el campo muestre el nombre del grupo. Se puede con esta forma de iterar seleccionar solo eso o ya depende de la informacion que envía el backend?

Comment: Pusiste `usuario.id` en lugar de `user.id`

Comment: Gracias! fue error al momento de escribir la pregunta. En la app esta bien. Los otros datos de la tabla se muestran bien. El problema es que al llegar al objeto group no me muestra nada y manda el error, dejando esos campos vacios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes iterar sobre un objeto. Tienes que hacer algo así en la parte del group.

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let users of listUsers">
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.id }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.Name }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.Email }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.Password }}</div>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let kv of users.group | keyvalue">
      <div>
        {{kv.key}}: {{ kv.value  }}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><i class="fas fa-edit text-primary"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ejemplo [funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umgunn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

## Edición

Puedes entrar directamente a la propiedad del objeto:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let users of listUsers">
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.id }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.Name }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.Email }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>{{ users.Password }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ users.group.name  }}
    </td>
    <td><i class="fas fa-edit text-primary"></i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dqof7v?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Gracias!! funciona, al menos ahora envia todo el objeto. Puedo de alguna forma solo mostrar el group name?. Por ahora voy a intentar ajustar eso desde el backend para que no me envie todo

Comment: No te entiendo. Puedes poner un ejemplo del resultado que quieres editando tu pregunta?

Comment: Claro! esta editada. Solo quiero saber si es posible, si no, no hay problema mi duda principal ya esta resuelta. Gracias!!

Comment: @Mat Si es posible!, actualize mi respuesta.

Comment: @Mat recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada mediante un click en el check verde :D